# Transform a timestamp to a date with "%m/%Y" format

Tags: python, python-3.x, date, timestamp

What is the best way to transform a `timestamp` (for instance: `2015-07-01 00:00:00`) to a date with the following format `"03/2017"` in Python 3?

Comment: [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html)?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, by `timestamp` you might mean a variable of `datetime` type. (considering your example)

The `datetime` class has a method `strftime`. strftime() is the method you are looking for.

For this specific example, it would look something like:

```
your_datetime.strftime("%m / %Y")
```

for more information read [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior).

If by `timestamp` you really mean a  [posix epoch time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) which you want to convert, your code would look like :

```
datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(your_datetime).strftime("%m / %Y")
```

And also your import statement should be :

```
import datetime
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `pd.Series.dt.strftime`:

```
import pandas as pd

s = pd.Series(pd.date_range(pd.Timestamp('now'), periods=2))

# 0   2018-03-31 22:57:30.819192
# 1   2018-04-01 22:57:30.819192
# dtype: datetime64[ns]

res = s.dt.strftime('%m/%Y')

# 0    03/2018
# 1    04/2018
# dtype: object
```